# Can one solve $ \int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin(xb)}{x^2+a^2}dx $ using contour integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, contour-integration, closed-form

Can one solves this using contour integration ?

> Indeed this look straightforward but having a close to it shows that we have some parity obstruction therein.

I have applied residues method the complex function $f(z) =\frac{e^{izb}}{z^2+a^2}$ but give the following

$$ \int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\sin(xb)}{x^2+a^2}dx = 0$$

Which is natural since the integrand is an odd function.
However this does not help to get the value of
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx$$

as opposed to  the following cases

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~~\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx$$ where the situation is more simpler. Where residues method gives of

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~~\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx =2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx $$ and one decues the values of the aforementioned  integral by parity. [Finding a contour to evaluate$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459454/finding-a-contour-to-evaluate-int-infty-infty-fracx-sin-xx2a2-dx)

> **Question:** How can one compute the above integral using Contour integral?
>
> Note I am also opened to any suggestion not using contour integration.

Comment: The integral $F(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^2+a^2}\,dx $ equals $\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(as)}{1+s^2}\,ds $, hence it depends on $\text{Si}$ and $\text{Ci}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  can I know why this phenomenon holds. because with cosine we have $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos ax}{x^2+1}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|a|}$$ which does not depends one SI and Ci see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487545)

Comment: But such integral is just half the integral over the whole real line, so it is not surprising. We have a parity obstruction in tackling the integral involving $\sin x$ through the same methods.